# what's the right syntax for importing single lodash methods with Rollup.js?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, rollupjs

I'm trying to learn [Rollup.js](http://rollupjs.org/).
I just want to try using only the delay() method from lodash, but can't find the right syntax. Tried various solutions but they seem not to work.

So,

```
npm install --save lodash
```

rollup config:

```
export default {
  input: 'src/app.js',
  output: {
    file: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs'
  }
};
```

src/app.js:

```
// here I've tried several syntaxes and paths..
import delay from 'node_modules/lodash/delay.js';
// import { delay } from 'lodash';
// import { delay } from 'lodash/dejay';
// import delay from 'lodash/dejay';

_.delay(function(){
  console.log('OK');
}, 1000);
```

I always get this message:

```
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
```

Also, strangely enough, If I take a look into the downloaded delay.js source, I find `module.exports = delay;` BUT, if I take a look to the github repo (same downloaded version: 4.17.15), I find `export default delay`: why????

Comment: Have you tried `const delay = require('lodash').delay;`?

Comment: You import as `delay`, but then you use `_.delay`?

Comment: @JKleinne OP wants to use ES6 module syntax

Comment: @JKleinne what do you mean by OP?

Comment: @Bergi meant [Original Poster](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/O/op_original_poster.html) which in this case is you. In any case, take a look at the [rollup.js documentation](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency) which could prove beneficial to your case.